# How can one use CURL to send a shell script as the POST body to Tornado?

Tags: shell, post, tornado

It is unclear to me how Tornado expects to parse body arguments for all content types. It makes sense for JSON, and maybe form data, but for other body content types it is unclear to me how to format the request with CURL to get it to work.

> **Question:** How can one use CURL to send a shell script as the POST body to Tornado? What is the formatting for the body arguments?

What I've tried:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-sh" http://localhost:8888/ -d script='#!/bin/bash \necho "scale=500\; 4*a(1)" | bc -l'
```

What I would hope or expect this to do is for Tornado to process the HTTP body so that (1) the body argument is `script`, and (2) the value corresponding to it is the shell script to compute pi:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scale=500\; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

Instead I just get a `400: Bad Request` error, and my debugging logs show that the value of `self.request.body_arguments` is an empty dictionary `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending POST data with this header - `Content-Type: application/x-sh`. But Tornado only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to parse submitted form/POST data.

Just submit the data with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and Tornado will make the submitted data available in `body_arguments`.

Comment: Alternately, keep the content-type, remove `script=` from the `-d` argument, and look in `self.request.body` instead of `self.request.body_arguments`. Unless you require compatibility with HTML forms, you can choose which protocol to use here.

Comment: I upvoted this but I don't have enough reputation for the vote to count yet. I appreciate the help!